# How can i change a specific label's text with a foreach loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried this before:

```
string st = "Unit";
foreach (Label lb in tabControl1.Items)
{
    if (st.IndexOf(lb.Name) != -1)
        lb.Content = "Some text";
}
```

Didn't work... 
Thank you for helping
EDIT: I did used .text instead of .content sorry.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a detailed enough diagnosis. Please tell us what happened.

Comment: I think you want to say  if (lb.Name.IndexOf(st) != -1).is that right?

Comment: @prashanth isnt that the same thing?

Comment: @JonSkeet I got a runtime error: 
"XamlParseException"

Comment: @IAmTheWalrus: Well that's pretty unlikely to be anything to do with your *code*, isn't it? And no, prashanth's suggestion *isn't* the same thing at all - you're currently seeing whether "Unit" contains the name of the label, (e.g. "ni" or "it") whereas you probably *want* to see if the name of the label contains "Unit" (e.g. "Unit test", "Unit price")

Comment: Also, programming GUI this way is generally considered an anti-pattern with MVVM being much more popular: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

use this method instead:

```
var control = this.FindName("button1");
```

but if you still want to serach every single item

- every TabeControl has TabeItems every TabeItem has a layout container
- (Grid for example) the container has Children property which is a
- collection of UIElements
- you can cast every child to a control and then do whatever you want

  var container = ((tabControl1.Items[0] as TabItem).Content as Panel);

  foreach(Control control in container)
  {
  // do what you want
  }

Comment: What do you mean? What should i do to fix it?

Comment: TabeControl Consists of 1 or more TabeItem
every tabeitem has it's controls

Comment: Do you mean 'in container.Children' ?

Comment: could it be you want the opposite of what you wrote??

-- like this:  lb.Name.IndexOf(st) 
which means find string in the name of control
and after i read the previous comments i say yes it's different from what you wrote

Comment: so it should work because it worked here 
set some break points get to work i can't help more than that

Answer (score 1):

## View.Xaml.cs

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string textdisplayed;

    public string Textdisplayed
    {
        get { return textdisplayed; }
        set
        {
            textdisplayed = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Textdisplayed"));
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Change the Text where ever you want Just Bind the Property `Textdispalyed` to you Label in XAML Properly..

## View.Xaml

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Textdisplayed,
                                 ElementName=mainWindow}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: I belive its the simplest.... nothing complex in it... its the generic WPF behavior (Binding and Automatic Value updation)..... This is always the prefred way.. but you are entitled to your opinion..